# Building a Nested JSON within looping

Tags: java, json

I am trying to build a JSON object of the following type

```
[
  {"Value":0,"Cities":["London","Tokyo","Washington"],"Name":"John"},
  {"Value":1,"Cities":["London","Tokyo","Washington"],"Name":"John"},
  {"Value":2,"Cities":["London","Tokyo","Washington"],"Name":"John"}
]
```

This is what I have done until now. The JSON object is written with the last entry.

```
   JSONArray outer = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
        str.add("London");
        str.add("Tokyo");
        str.add("Washington");

        int res = 3;


        for(int i=0;i<res;i++){
            js.put("Value", i);
            js.put("Name", "John");
            js.put("Cities", str);
            outer.add(js);          
        }           
        System.out.println(outer);
```

What I am getting now is:

```
  [
    {"Value":2,"Cities":["London","Tokyo","Washington"],"Name":"John"},
    {"Value":2,"Cities":["London","Tokyo","Washington"],"Name":"John"},
    {"Value":2,"Cities":["London","Tokyo","Washington"],"Name":"John"}
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new JSONObject each time, *inside* the loop.

```
JSONArray outer = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject js = null;
    List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    str.add("London");
    str.add("Tokyo");
    str.add("Washington");

    int res = 3;


    for(int i=0;i<res;i++){
        js= new JSONObject();
        js.put("Value", i);
        js.put("Name", "John");
        js.put("Cities", str);
        outer.add(js);          
    }           
    System.out.println(outer);
```

Also, you'll probably get the same issue if changing cities anytime, so unless they will always remain the required three, create a new list for every object.

Comment: Yes, this was a dummy example. I understand the problem now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new JSON object for each Value,Name, Cities pair.
So you need to put it inside second for loop. Like this

```
for(int i=0;i<res;i++){
        js= new JSONObject();
```